# strings don't function properly

Tags: c, string, token, strtok, strlen

I have another problem concerning C :( what I want to do with this function is check for numbers in a token and if there are none I put that token in a string, which I later print to file. My function looks like this:
const char *tarpas = " ";

```
{
    const char *space = " ";
    char *token, B[255];
    int i, length, found = 0, x = 0;
    token = strtok(A, space);
    while(token != NULL){
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
            if((token[i] >= '0') && (token[i] <= '9')) found++; //If found a number
        }                                                       //increase found
        if(found == 0){                            //if found = 0 means the word is clean
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
                B[x] = token[i];
                x++;
            }
            B[x] = ' ';                //adds a space after the token is in string
            x++;          
        }
        rado = 0;
        token = strtok(NULL, tarpas); // get another token
    }
    print(B);
    memset(B, 0, strlen(B));          //clear B string
    }
```

My data file:

```
ta5iip r345ytas suraitytas o rytoj gimimo rytas
asdasdasd
asdasd
```

My result file:

```
asdasd \
  rytoj gimimo rytas
 (
```

What it should be:

```
suraitytas o rytoj gimimo rytas
asdasdasd
asdasd
```

Thank you for any kind of input!!!

Comment: Use "isdigit" instead of your pair of conditions. Use (memset B, 0, sizeof B) instead of scanning an additional time - and initialize B before use as well. What does "rado" do? I recommend putting the strtok calls into a single for loop, instead of spacing them. What is the reason you use different delimiter pointers in the different strtok calls?

Comment: @mpez0 `isdigit(token[i])` is undefined behavior if `token[i] < 0` and not `EOF`.  `(token[i] >= '0') && (token[i] <= '9')` does not have this problem.

Comment: @chux my man pages say isdigit is defined for any unsigned char or EOF. Whether "char" defaults to signed or unsigned is implementation dependent -- I agree that defining B as unsigned char would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `found` in each iteration of the while loop.

Also you have to exit loop

```
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
        if((token[i] >= '0') && (token[i] <= '9')) found++; //If found a number
    }
```

if a digit was found in the string.

This loop could be rewritten the following way

```
size_t n = strlen(token);
i = 0;
while ( i < n && ( token[i] < '0' || token[i] > '9' ) ++i;
found = i != n;
```

It seems also that you read strings with function `fgets` that includes the new line character. You should remove this character from the string.

ANd place statement

```
memset(B, 0, strlen(B));
```

before the while loop or initially initialize array B to zeroes

Comment: Thank you and @molbdnilo for clearing it up for me :) I have managed to fix part of the problems, now when I print the strings to the screen the second and third line are pushed by a space and the result file still seems to be messed up, any ideas?

Comment: @Dominykas Ber  From the code you showed it is difficult to say what else is wrong. Try to ask a new question with your updated code.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, all of you have been a great help :) I have fixed the whitespace issue, now all that is left is printing

Comment: @Dominykas Ber Because there is no code of function print in your question then I advice to ask a new question relative to function print. But before to ask the question you shoulw check the string at least by using function puts that outputs its parameter on console.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `found` to zero inside the loop.

Since you find a digit in the first token, that means that you never execute the `if(found == 0)` code.

This, in turn, means that when you print `B`, it's still uninitialised and you're printing some random data.

You should initialise `B`:

```
char B[255] = {0};
```

and add

```
found = 0;
```

as the first line of the loop.
Or, since you have no use of `found` outside the loop, move it inside the loop.

```
while(token != NULL){
    int found = 0;
    /* ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize found variable inside the while loop. Also as @BLUEPIXY mentioned, B array needs to be ended  with '\0'.
So the code would be as following

```
{
const char *space = " ";
char *token, B[255];
int i, length, found = 0, x = 0;
token = strtok(A, space);
while(token != NULL){
    found = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
        if((token[i] >= '0') && (token[i] <= '9')) found++; //If found a number
    }                                                       //increase found
    if(found == 0){                            //if found = 0 means the word is clean
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(token); i++){
            B[x] = token[i];
            x++;
        }
        B[x] = ' ';                //adds a space after the token is in string
        x++;          
    }
    rado = 0;
    token = strtok(NULL, tarpas); // get another token
}
B[x] = '\0';
print(B);
memset(B, 0, strlen(B));          //clear B string
}
```